# 2D Animated Face, Is posible to drive the x-uv offset on Blender

Tags: animation, texturing, uv, bones, drivers

So I wanted for a lot of time to do a model with an animated texture by face for a game and I stumbled with this video:

[2D Eyes Maya to UE4](Https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pvLG4rmkB8A)

On it, they achieved the thing I'm searching for in Maya, driving the x-uv offset with the bone rotation. In Blender this is achieved by setting a grid with the faces and positioning a target that warps the uv (with a modifier) to select which face to use, thing is that translating that grid to UE4 can be troublesome that's why I want to do it with bone rotation, so I came with this method

[image: My method]

I arranged the faces in a circle in the texture and set the uv center in the middle so when I rotate the faces would change like the video, but I want to improve that its hard to arrange, align and edit faces like that, so, I wanna know if it is posible to drive the x-uv offset on Blender like the guys in the video do in Maya, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it in a weird manner, what I did was place another bone so uv warp target, pointer and controller, and I used a driver to drive the location of the x axis of the pointer bone with the Y rotation of controller bone.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using Multiple **MixRGB** nodes.

On Each of the nodes, I add a driver as follows (Being Sure to increment my numerator along the way):

[image: Step 001 Driver Setup]

[image: Step_002_Material_Node_Layout]

When I'm all done it should look similar to this...

[image: Step_003_Complete_Node_Layout]

Then When I rotate my empty my image texture changes as follows:

[image: Step_004_Resulting_Animation]

Comment: Possible Bug - I personally kept running into a material failure (MAGENTA EVERYWHERE) if I used more than 24 images, not sure if this is an uncaught 2.8 bug or not. Can someone confirm? My images were 960x540 .png format